# Evaluate bash string into an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, split

I'm using a VS Code task to run a script that runs my jest tests on the currently opened file.  It prompts me to type in a test pattern and, if something is entered, passes the value in as an environment variable. I want to split that variable an array to be modified passed in as arguments to my `jest` call.  Because test names almost always include spaces (or any other character), I want to be able to be able to pass multiple patterns with quotes around them.

Input

```
"test 1" "test 2" "test 3"
```

Generated environment variables

```bash
args='"test 1" "test 2" "test 3"'
testFile="path/to/currently opened/file"
```

Desired command to run in script:

```bash
npm run test -- "path/to/currently opened/file" -t "test 1" -t "test 2" -t "test 3"
```

I've figured out how to do everything except evaluate `$args` as an array.  Here's what I have to test various attempts at parsing this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "$args"
echo

scriptArgs=( $args )
echo ${#scriptArgs}
echo ${#scriptArgs[@]}
echo

scriptArgs=( "${args[@]}" )
echo ${#scriptArgs}
echo ${#scriptArgs[@]}
echo

scriptArgs=( "$args" )
echo ${#scriptArgs}
echo ${#scriptArgs[@]}
echo

scriptArgs=( $(echo $args) )
echo ${#scriptArgs}
echo ${#scriptArgs[@]}
echo

scriptArgs=( "$(echo $args)" )
echo ${#scriptArgs}
echo ${#scriptArgs[@]}
echo

# prints:
#
#  "test 1" "test 2" "test 3"
#  
#  5
#  6
#  
#  26
#  1
#  
#  26
#  1
#  
#  5
#  6
#  
#  26
#  1
```

The desired value is 3.

Comment: If you could easily convert a string like `args` into an array, there wouldn't be a need for arrays in the first place.

Comment: @dx_over_dt : Why don't you simply define `args` as array? `args=('test 1' 'test 2' 'test 3')`?

Comment: @user1934428 I don't have that option.  VS Code ensures that the environment is a single escaped value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `eval` to get the quotes processed.

```
eval "scriptArgs=($args)"
```

Comment: Well that was easy.  It's good to learn the `eval` keyword exists.